# RuntimeError: unreachable in rustwasm

Tags: rust, webassembly

I am getting the error "RuntimeError: unreachable in rustwasm" for the code

error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: unreachable
    at __rust_start_panic (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[346]:0x274ec)
    at rust_panic (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[254]:0x26d0b)
    at std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hb07b303a83b6d242 (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[168]:0x24a47)
    at rust_begin_unwind (http://127.0.0.1:8080/wasm_bg.wasm:wasm-function[228]:0x267ed)
    at core::panicking::panic_fmt::h62f7e605cdf65d83 
    at core::panicking::panic_bounds_check::ha440f41d0e4eca5f 
    at virtualdom::parseNode::h9ba47b7b20126d66 
    at run ()
    at init ()
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ac403a9043e49b7a2fc3814a692b8d49

I have following questions ?

1. is it coming from `parseNode` function?
2. is it because of `dm.children[i]` overflowed? or some functions removed at runtime in the background in wasm?
3. I tried to hook `panic::set_hook(Box::new(console_error_panic_hook::hook));` but did not help much! How should I debug these kind of errors?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `dm.children.len()` is `1` so immediately after the first iteration of the while loop, then `i` becomes `1` which triggers the panic as `1` is out of bounds.

The easiest way to fix this, is to replace the while loop with a for loop instead, and match the `Node::Element` variant inside the for loop.

```
for child in dm.children {
    if let Node::Element(x) = child {
        let nod = Node1 {
            tag: x.name,
            props: x.classes,
            children: x.children,
        };

        println!("{:?}", nod.tag);
        createElement(&nod);
    }
}
```

*Note that you're not handling the result which `createElement()` returns.*

Since this specific code you're having issues with doesn't *really* have any specific WASM/web related things. Then you could just compile that code as a regular Rust binary for testing, which would give you more helpful errors and simplify testing.

Comment: Thank you. I would like iterate or loop through children's child as well and need to call createElement() for each. How should I write loop for that ? Thanks in advance